# Error while upgrading  to Rails 2.3.11 (HashWithIndifferentAccess error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, url-validation

Whenever I attempt to create or update an environment that our app uses, I get the following:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `base_url' for #<HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x107162f08>):
  app/controllers/environments_controller.rb:64:in `check_base_url_for_https'
  app/controllers/environments_controller.rb:56:in `update'
  haml (3.0.22) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:41:in `call'
  airbrake (3.0.4) lib/airbrake/rack.rb:27:in `call'
  airbrake (3.0.4) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
```

As I stated in the title, I recently upgraded to Rails 2.3.11. This error never occurred before. Here is the code in my environments_controller.rb that is being executed when the error occurs:

```
def check_base_url_for_https
  @environment = params[:environment]
  if /^https:\/\//i =~ @environment.base_url 
    @ajax_flash = "<ul class='notice'><li>The website you are trying to test is a secure site.  If you are using self-signed SSL certificates please see our <a href='http://support.janova.us'>Support Site</a> and search for SSL for important tips on how to access your site.</li></ul>"
  end
end
```

Does anyone know why this code (specifically the line `if /^https:\/\//i =~ @environment.base_url` no longer works in Rails 2.3.11?

I would like to add that the code in my app/models/environment.rb appears to be sound too:

```
def base_url 
  self[:base_url].try(:gsub, /\$/, '') 
end
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with the code above?

Comment: can you use `root_url` instead ?

Comment: I did try root_url and got the same error.

Comment: Have you actually checked what the `@environment` variable contains? The error message suggests that it's an instance of `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, and that that class doesn't have a `base_url` method, which seems quite reasonable. Try to print `@environment.inspect` to the log and see what comes out.

Comment: Yes, I did look to see what is contained in @environment. It looks right to me. This is what @environment.inspect returns: `{"name"=>"Janova HTML Reference", "dns_mapping_domain_name"=>"", "ssh_user"=>"", "ssh_host"=>"", "default"=>"0", "ssh_port"=>"", "base_url"=>"http://janova-reference.heroku.com", "dns_mapping_ip_address"=>""}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: `params[:environment]` was defined as a hash. Thank you, Frost, for forcing me to see this. Therefore, I changed the line `@environment = params[:environment]` to `@environment = Environment.new(params[:environment])` and it worked.